# Selective copying from one file to another using bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that will copy a file taking certain numbers out of the file and making them the Header. The original file looks like:

```
    #
    # Rotational transition: j= **3**--> **8**
    #
    # Threshold energy **0.72598151E-01** eV 
    #
    0.01000019 0.000000
    0.03000057 0.000000
    ...
```

I have made bold the features I wish to copy as a header so the output file will look like:

```
    3 8 0.72598151E-01
    #
    # Rotational transition: j= **3**--> **8**
    #
    # Threshold energy **0.72598151E-01** eV 
    #
    0.01000019 0.000000
    0.03000057 0.000000
    ...
```

I want this script to copy a bunch of files which will all have the same layout as the above but with the numbers going into the header different on each file. My script to copy the file is far is:

```
    echo > newFile
    while read -r line
        do 
        echo $line >> newFile
        done < originalFile
    done
```

Thank you very much for your help

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but you get the idea:

```
FIRST=$(head -n2 "$1" | grep 'Rotational transition' | sed 's/.*j=//; s/\s//g; s/-->/ /')
SECOND=$(head -n4 "$1" | grep 'Threshold energy' | sed 's/.*energy //; s/ eV//')
echo "$FIRST $SECOND" > "$2"
cat "$1" >> "$2"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this seems very close to a solution. I can see how the lines inside the $((...)) are extracting the correct information from the file. However when I try to run this code I get an error: "syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is...) " and it says the error token is what is inside the $((...)) .

Comment: Stupid me, I ofcourse ment `$(...)` not `$((...))` edited the answer, now works in my test.